# Parse.com: How do I return the session token?

Tags: parse-platform

I've created a signUp function for my app to call, and the Parse.com backend JS code to sign the user up.

Sure enough, the user will appear in the database. Heck, I even got the verification email to be sent (something that was *much* harder than it should be. It is a setting under the "settings" section of the main parse backend, not something that is programatically set).

Now I'm trying to get the sessionToken from the newly signed up user. Returning the "user" object on success of the signup and inspecting, I don't see a "sessionToken". I also don't see a sessionToken in the  user database...

Can somebody give me some code that will return the sessionToken?

Here is the relevant code:

```
user.signUp(null, {
  success: function(user) {
    response.success(user);
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

I don't get a sessionToken here. Where do I get it from?

Comment: It is odd that the Android and iOS libraries include a sessionToken but there is absolutely no reference to the sessionToken in the Javascript API.It looks like according to https://parse.com/questions/is-it-possible-to-keep-a-user-logged-in-after-signing-up-logging-in-via-the-rest-api  that the javascript api just stores the session token into a cookie. Take a look at your cookie values. I bet you can pull it out of there directly.

Comment: @rdrobinson3 hey man, can you write up what you wrote as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code i ended up using looked something like this:

```
endpoint : "https://api.parse.com/1/login",
    parameters : getTheLoginParametersFrom(user),
    success : function(response) {
        tablesModule.saveSessionId(response.sessionToken);
    }
}
```

Where the result from the "login" is the response.sessionToken.

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to check on your local storage:

Local Storage Report

There are 5 items in local storage, using 0.9KB (0.001MB)

Parse/bqfSO3dVttG65a8CIkC1SdqC0CCqiqYsp1EfsjL8/currentUser

username    XXX@gmail.com
email           XXX@gmail.com
objectId    oVGKr1vdbG
createdAt   2013-03-20T17:17:54.815Z
updatedAt   2013-03-20T17:17:54.815Z
_id         oVGKr1vdbG
_sessionToken   12aob7us2lj18pkaddkbvsal7

That is what Parse checks when you do:

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
var sessionToken = Parse.User.current()._sessionToken;
```